# cannot return getaddress from latlon using request module function outside another function in sails controller

Tags: sails.js

SailsJS: In my controller i have two function first one is allvehicleRecord()  and another function getLocation(latlng)  which get the address from google geocode using request module..
my problem is i cannot  call the  getLocation(latlng) function in  allvehicleRecord() for getting in dataArray. its return me "undefine"
 need help....

var request = require('request');

```
getvehicle:function(req,res){


            function cb(data){
            if(data){
                var formatData=formatresult(data);
             }
               res.json(formatData);
             };
            try
            {
              if(!req.user.id)
              {
                console.log("nt defined");

              }}catch(e){
                console.log("exception");
                 return;
             }

            var userID=req.user.id;
            var vehicleView = VehicleView.getvehicleStatus(userID,cb);
            function formatresult(data)
            {
              var dataArray = new Array();
              for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
              {
                var Lat = data[i].Lat;
                var Lon = data[i].Lon;
                 var latlng=Lat+','+Lon;
                //getLocation
              var dataAddress = getLocation(latlng);
              console.log(dataAddress);

                dataArray.push({dataAddress: dataAddress});
             }

             return dataArray;
            };



         }
```

function getLocation(latlng) {
        var latlong = latlng;

```
 var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" +latlong+ "&sensor=false";
request({url: url,
        json: true

        },function (error, data, textStatus) {
    if (!error && data.statusCode === 200) {

      // if (textStatus && textStatus.length > 0)

       streetaddress=(textStatus);

       var address = streetaddress.results[0].formatted_address;
       console.log(address);
       return address;

  }


  });


 }
```

Comment: Well, what I understand is you are having problem while making an ajax call to google api, and where you expecting response, you are getting undefined. Have you tried this url in browser ? are these variables (which you are passing in URL) are valid ?

Comment: @Omar no problem in conversion of getaddress from lat lon also browser url return me json successful. my problem is call in getvehicle function.